# Running a macro automatically

Tags: excel, vba

I want a macro to run automatically everytime I navigate to a specific worksheet. I know this is possible because there is another macro on the worksheet that updates information automatically, but I can't seem to figure out how to set it so that my new macro will run automatically. Note all of the macros are in the same folder "Modules."

Comment: Have you tried using a `Workbook_SheetActivate` event? [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195710(v=office.15).aspx) is the documentation for the same.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be along the lines of what you need.  If you are in the VBA editor, on the left navigator pane, double click the sheet you are interested in having run the code automatically.  In the window that opens, on the upper left change the drop down to "Worksheet".  Then in the upper right drop down, change the event handler to "Activate"

You should see a new blank sub generate:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    'put some code here
End Sub
```

Now anytime you activate that sheet, any code you enter in that sub will be run automatically.  You can look at the event handlers in the right drop and try other ones if they suite your needs better.